# How to visualize a multidimensional php array

Tags: php, emacs, multidimensional-array

I have a very big php array that I've saved in a textfile. I need to access the content of an element in the array but to do that I need to know all the keys to it and because of it size it's kind of hard to read. I would like some kind of method/tool to for example collapse irrelevant branches of the array to make it easier to read the path leading to the relevant item.

I usually use either emacs or less to view testfiles but I suspect there is nothing connected to these programs that does what I want(?).

Comment: http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/collapsible.html ? You can just recursively iterate the array and output a set of `<ul>`s, apply one of many collapsible list jQuery plugins to each level?

Comment: Have you tried `echo '<pre>'.print_r($yourArray,true).'</pre>';`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to store `json_encode(array)` into Json file instead of text file. 
It is easy to read json file and easy to convert json string to array.

Comment: No need to **bold** your entire answer ! and please explain to me what the difference is between a *json file* and a *text file* ???!!!??

Comment: Json file can easily read and convert to PHP Array
with json_decode(file_get_contents("file_name",true))

Answer (score 0):

Use http://krumo.sourceforge.net/